# Different ways to alias a column

Tags: sql, alias

What is the difference between

```
select  empName as EmployeeName from employees
```

versus

```
select  EmployeeName = empName from employees
```

from a technical point of view. Not sure if this is just SQL server specific or not.

Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd prefer the first one, since the second one is not portable -

```
select  EmployeeName = empName from employees
```

is either a syntax error (at least in SQLite and Oracle), or it might not give you what you expect (comparing two columns EmployeeName and empName and returning the comparison result as a boolean/integer), whereas

```
select  empName EmployeeName from employees
```

is the same as

```
  select  empName as EmployeeName from employees
```

which is my preferred  variant.

Comment: Are sure that `select  EmployeeName empName from employees` is valid sql?

Comment: @Jon if EmployeeName is the name of the column in the table, yes I'm pretty sure it is valid SQL :-)

Comment: The syntax is valid, but I think Frank Schmitt got the columns mixed up from my previous query. The column in the table is empName while the output should be aliased as EmployeeName so syntax would be 'select empName EmployeeName from employees' is correct SQL.

Comment: @ManiP - nice one - thought I was going mad!

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage of the second syntax is that it allows the column aliases to be all lined up which can be of benefit for long expressions.

```
SELECT foo,
       bar,
       baz = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY bar)
FROM T
```

Comment: Since SQL doesn't care about whitespace, can't you line them up in either case?

Comment: @Alison R. You could do, but its more work having to make the white spaces. Plus, if something changes in the data item, then the white space will have to be adjusted again

Comment: @Alison - Yes. "Allow" was the wrong word but that would mean `baz` in my example wrapping onto 2 lines. One with the expression and the next with the alias.

Comment: For the record, I've been using the 1st preference for years now, but this point has made me think twice!

Comment: I'd use the second syntax if **all** the columns were aliased. If only a few are, I get confused when reading, trying to figure out if a given line starts with the data being returned, or just the alias.

Comment: Having the alias names on the left makes it a lot easier to read in many cases.  For example; The field name should indicated what the code does, giVing insight before you read and SQL.  All queries in an SP tend ot have field names in the same column on the screen, making them much easy to spot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a technical difference. Its mainly preferential. I go for the second as its easier to spot columns in big queries, especially if the query is properly indented.