# Do these SQL queries return the exact same result?

Tags: sql

Is the result of these two queries the same?

```
Select MIN(create_time) a, accounts FROM table1
```

... and ...

```
Select MIN(create_time) AS a, accounts FROM table1
```

Comment: `AS` is an optional keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125433/different-ways-to-alias-a-column read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the same.

Also, if your alias is ever composed out of more words, then you should use it between double quotes.

Like this :

```
Select MIN(create_time) "MINIMUM TIME", accounts FROM table1
```

A I have said, this version is also equivalent:

```
Select MIN(create_time) AS "MINIMUM TIME", accounts FROM table1
```

Comment: @almoujtahed You're welcome, I hope everything's clear. Don't forget upvoting and/or marking the correct answer everytime you ask a question.

Comment: identifiers in SQL need to be enclosed in double quotes. Single quotes denote string literals. `'MINIMUM TIME'` is a string, `"MINIMUM TIME"` is an identifier (in this case a column alias)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the comment. I have modified my answer.