# Insert hashbytes Incorrect syntax near 'MD5'

Tags: sql, sql-server, hashbytes

I'm using SQL Server 2014.  As part of a larger task, I need to detect updates etc from a table so am implementing Hashbytes. The Hasbytes field is defined as `varbinary(MAX)`.

This is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_People
  SELECT
    id,
    Name,
    Add1,
    Add2,
    Add3,
    HashValue as Hashbytes('MD5',CONCAT('|',Name, Add1, Add2, Add3))
from tbl_PeopleSource
```

However, I just keep receiving the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'MD5'.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's `SELECT ID, .., Hashbytes('MD5',CONCAT('|',Name, Add1, Add2, Add3)) AS HashByte`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a comma just before the `HashValue` alias, to separate `Add3` from the next column. Also the alias is inverted, should be `<expression> as AliasName`.

```
Add3, -- Here comma
Hashbytes('MD5',CONCAT('|',Name, Add1, Add2, Add3)) as HashValue -- Inverted alias
```

Also it's good practice to list the inserted table's column so the order doesn't get wrongly interpreted:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_People (
    ID,
    Name,
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    HashValue)
SELECT
    ...
```

There are [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125433/different-ways-to-alias-a-column) to use column aliases on SQL Server.